# Windmeter not connecting

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9

I am intergrating wind meter in my own application using `WindMeterSDK`( https://github.com/WeatherFlow/WindMeterSDK ) but my wind meter is not connecting to app.

I am using demo code of this sdk

```
sensor = [[WindMeterSDK alloc] init];

    [sensor reportValueChange:^(AnemometerObservation *value){

        self.latestObservation = value;
        if ([self.latestObservation.statusCode intValue] == OK) {
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                console.text = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ (%@):  %f mps @ %f° (%f, %f)\n", self.latestObservation.timestamp, self.latestObservation.timezone, [self.latestObservation.windSpeed floatValue], [self.latestObservation.windDirectionDegreesTrue floatValue], [[value.deviceLocation objectForKey:@"latitude"] floatValue], [[self.latestObservation.deviceLocation objectForKey:@"longitude"] floatValue]] stringByAppendingString:console.text];
                NSLog(@"%@",[self.latestObservation prettyJsonString]);
            });
        } else if ([self.latestObservation.statusCode intValue] == ANEMOMTER_NOT_CONNECTED) {
            console.text = [@"DEVICE NOT CONNECTED!\n" stringByAppendingString:console.text];
            NSLog(@"DEVICE NOT CONNECTED!");
        }
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

This might look silly but have you imported file

## import "WindMeterSDK.h"

in your controller.

Also this step is really important
**Assure the following linker flags have been set: "-ObjC", "-all_load" and "-lc++"**
Check Linker search Path in Build Settings

Comment: have you implemented windmeter in your app.

Comment: no, but if you are still getting same problem, then try reinstalling the library. It might work

Comment: Delete link search Paths and Add them again . Also add "$inherited" in your path